# How can I make my script save the copy to a specific folder?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the below script to make a copy of my google worksheet (values and formatting only).  However, this script is placing the new file in my main google drive and I want the file to be saved to an archive folder.  How can I edit my script to do this?

```
function copySheetValuesV4(){
    var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceSheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.create('03_'+sourceSpreadsheet.getName()+' _December 2017');
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceSheets.length; i++){
        var sourceSheet = sourceSheets[i];
        if (!sourceSheet.isSheetHidden()) {
            var sourceSheetName = sourceSheet.getSheetName();
            var sValues = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
            sourceSheet.copyTo(destination)
            var destinationSheet = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of '+sourceSheetName).setName(sourceSheetName);

            destinationSheet.getRange(1,1,sValues.length,sValues[0].length).setValues(sValues);// overwrite all formulas that the copyTo preserved */

        }
        destination.getSheetByName("sheet1").hideSheet() // Remove the default "sheet1" */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id).addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(destination.getId()))`. This gets the spreadsheet ID and then adds the spreadsheet to a folder.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **why** and/or **how** this code answers the question improves its long-term value.